# How to upload files to AWS S3 directly from the browser(Front-end) using preSigned PUT URLS in Vanilla JavaScript with Axios

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, browser, axios, frontend

If you would like to upload files directly to AWS S3 from the browser without having to proxy that upload request through your own servers or even expose your AWS S3 credentials in your front end, you can use pre-signed URLs which make this process easy. Here is a simple and straight forward code to help you do that

Answer (score 3):

The server-side code for getting presigned AWS S3 URLS using ExpressJS

```
app.get("/get-signed-url", function(req, res, next){
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
   ...
  });
  const {name, contentType} = req.body;
  const params = {
    Bucket: "<your-bucket-name>",
    Key: name,
    Expires: (30 * 60), //30mins
    ContentType: contentType
  };
  s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", params, (err, url)=>{
    return res.json({url});
  });
});
```

The client-side or browser code

```
import axios from "axios";
async function doS3Upload (evt) {
  const file = evt.target.files[0];
  const {data} = await axios.post("/get-signed-url", {
    name: file.name, contentType: file.type || "application/octet-stream; charset=binary"
  });
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", async () => {
    const response = await axios({
      url: data.url,
      method: "put",
      data: reader.result,
      headers: { "Content-Type" : file.type },
      maxContentLength: (100 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024),
      timeout: (30 * 60 * 1000),//30mins
      onUploadProgress: (pevt) => {
        console.log("uploaded.:" + Math.round((pevt.loaded/pevt.total) * 100);
      }
    });
  });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
};
```

Per @Endless' suggestion, using the File object instead

```
import axios from "axios";
async function doS3Upload (evt) {
 const file = evt.target.files[0];
 const {data} = await axios.post("/get-signed-url", {
   name: file.name, contentType: file.type || 
   "application/octet-stream; charset=binary"
 });

 const response = await axios({
     url: data.url,
     method: "put",
     data: file,
     headers: { "Content-Type" : file.type },
     maxContentLength: (100 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024),
     timeout: (30 * 60 * 1000),//30mins
     onUploadProgress: (pevt) => {
       console.log("uploaded.:" + 
       Math.round((pevt.loaded/pevt.total) * 100);
     }
  });
};
```

Comment: Don't waste time using the FileReader, send the file instead `data: file`

Comment: Thanks Endless, I will revise accordingly